# Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon

Tags: linux, centos, sshd

I am  using centos7.

I was trying to change the port of ssh and I changed the the port in /usr/lib/firewalld/services/ssh.xml

I also change the port in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file

But when I tried to start the sshd service by "systemctl start sshd" then I am getting the following error.

```
sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-03-27 
16:36:20 IST; 26s ago
 Docs: man:sshd(8)
       man:sshd_config(5)
 Process: 20420 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS (code=exited, 
status=255)
Main PID: 20420 (code=exited, status=255)

Mar 27 16:36:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sshd.service: main process 
exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Mar 27 16:36:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenSSH 
server daemon.
Mar 27 16:36:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered 
failed state.
Mar 27 16:36:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sshd.service failed.
```

Comment: paste the output of `tail -500 /var/log/secure | grep 'sshd'`.

Comment: Is the port already in use by another service?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/538037/sshd-service-fails-to-start

Comment: If you have SELinux enabled (`getenforce` shows "Enforcing"), you will need to adapt the security policy to allow `sshd` to listen to a port other than the default 22.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the new port no in /etc/services files as well,

### example:

ssh             22/tcp                          # The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
ssh             22/udp                          # The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol

Also check SELinux, as you need to specify the non standard port using semanage tool.

I recommend to visit the REDHAT article to change the port no,

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_confined_services/sect-managing_confined_services-configuration_examples-changing_port_numbers

Comment: It is not necessary (nor desirable) to modify the list of _standard_ port assignments in `/etc/services` to match the current local configuration for a service.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue while changing the port from 22.

Upon checking found that SELinux Status is enabled. I have disabled it and check again. Though it was enabled. SELinux Staus will not be changed until you restart your system.

**Disabling SELinux and rebooting system fixed my issue and able to change SSH Port.**

Comment: The user (presumably) want SSH to be available on a non-standard port as a way of obfuscation, which would provide a low level (but still) of protection. Disabling another security mechanism to make this work seems like a bad trade-off.